# Error JavaFX when adding selected element from tableView to observableArrayList

Tags: java, javafx

I have a problem with JavaFX and exactly when adding the selected row in the table to the new list. The thing is that it adds an item to the list, but each time you click on the button the item is overwritten. I would like it to work this way:  the current status of the list + next record and next...
I do not know how fix this .
Bellow i pasted the code

```
@FXML
void getTheValueFromTable() {

    Materials selectItem = TableId.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

    listOfChooseMaterial = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    listOfChooseMaterial.add(selectItem);

}

@FXML
void viewList() {

    System.out.println("size list" + listOfChooseMaterial.size());

    for (Materials material : listOfChooseMaterial) {

        System.out.println(material.getNameM());
        System.out.println(material.getPriceM());
    }

}
```

In this first method I get a value from `tablevView` / `arrayList` and in the second method I try to show all the records in the list, but I still have one. Although the method was called several times (click on the button).

all code of class`

```
@FXML
private TableView<Materials> TableId;

@FXML
private Button butt2;

@FXML
private TableColumn<?, ?> NameId;

@FXML
private TableColumn<?, ?> PriceId;

@FXML
private TableColumn<?, ?> TypeId;

@FXML
private TableColumn<?, ?> WydId;

@FXML
private Button butt1;

@FXML
private Button butt3;

ObservableList<Materials> listOfChooseMaterial;

@FXML
private void initialize() {

    configure();
    TableId.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    loadProjectsToTableView();

}

public List<Materials> getAllMaterials() {

    TypedQuery<Materials> creareQuery = entityManager.createQuery("select m from Materials m", Materials.class);
    List<Materials> resultMaterialsList = creareQuery.getResultList();
    entityManager.close();
    entityManagerFactory.close();
    return resultMaterialsList;

}

public void configure() {

    NameId.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("nameM"));
    PriceId.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("priceM"));
    TypeId.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("typeM"));
    WydId.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("preformanceM"));
}

public void loadProjectsToTableView() {

    TableId.getItems().clear();

    ObservableList<Materials> listOfMaterials;

    listOfMaterials = FXCollections.observableArrayList(getAllMaterials());

    TableId.setItems(listOfMaterials);

}

@FXML
void getTheValueFromTable() {

    Materials selectItem = TableId.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

    listOfChooseMaterial = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    listOfChooseMaterial.add(selectItem);

}

@FXML
void viewList() {

    System.out.println("size list" + listOfChooseMaterial.size());

    for (Materials material : listOfChooseMaterial) {

        System.out.println(material.getNameM());
        System.out.println(material.getPriceM());
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Correct me if wrong. Doesn't `listOfChooseMaterial = FXCollections.observableArrayList();` re-initialize the `ObservableList<Materials> listOfChooseMaterial` every time you call `void getTheValueFromTable()` method?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yes, exacly, this metod is run when i click the button.

Comment: So why are you creating a new list every time you click the button? Surely that completely defeats what you are trying to do.

Comment: I did not know that it worked, but I moved the initialization to another method and it works!!